# INSERT values from "group by" query into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, insert

```
SELECT sku, sum(quantity)
FROM orders
WHERE "location" = 'Location - 1'
group by sku;
```

This returns 2 columns:

Col1 = Sku
Col2 = sums of quantity for each sku

I have another table that contains skus in Col1.
I then want to insert into table2 the values from Col2 where Col1 = table2.col1 (matches on orders.sku and table2.sku, inserts sum value for orders.sku)

Comment: You speak of "insert", but it sounds like you want to *update*?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted a `select` `insert` like this one:

```
insert into table2(sku, result)
select sku, sum(quantity) as result
from orders
group by sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you really want to [**`UPDATE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

```
UPDATE table2 t
SET    col2 = o.sum_q
FROM  (
   SELECT sku, sum(quantity) AS sum_q
   FROM   orders
   WHERE  location = 'Location - 1'
   GROUP  BY sku
   ) o
WHERE  t.sku = o.sku
AND    t.col2 IS DISTINCT FROM o.sumq;
```

The last line is optional, but typically a good idea to avoid empty updates. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)